# Spring security get authorization header value

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Currently I have a RestController ProductsController that takes a basic Authorization string.

We have some external security library defined that can not be changed.
The security library has the security config defined and reads the Auth and translates it to a principal without the password or the original string. the principal just have the username present.

I need to extract the auth that was passed in the header without changing the sec lib, Can you please let me know how can i do that?? we use spring boot and spring security with java 11.

Comment: The principal never has the password so not sure what the problem is. If you need the header then just get the header. I also wonder if you already use Spring Security why do it again in your controller, seems a duplication of things and not doing things (authentication/authorization) where it belongs. All in all it feels like you are working around Spring Security and trying to implement your own security...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read all http header in your Spring Boot application, we use the same @RequestHeader annotation. To collect all the header values, we have the option to collect values in to Map, a MultiValueMap or a HttpHeaders object. Let’s see how to do this:

```
@RestController
public class AllHeaderController {

    @GetMapping("/print-all-headers")
    public void getAllheaders(@RequestHeader Map<String,String> headers){
        headers.forEach((key,value) ->{
            System.out.println("Header Name: "+key+" Header Value: "+value);
        });
    }
}
```